# How to get jquery value from for loop in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to alert the text of a div which is in a for loop when it is clicked. There are many divs with same id, i want to get 3 if i click the 3rd or 2 when 2nd is clicked. How can i make it with the following code or what must i add to it? Thank you.

```
<? for($i=0; $i<5; $i­­++) { ?>
    <div id="abc"><? echo $i ?></div>
<? } ?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#abc").click(function() {
            var thevar= $("#abc").text();
            alert (thevar);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: id should be unique..!  :/

Comment: You're missing a few closing brackets (`); });`) at the end of your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use a `class` instead of using `id` inside that loop,

```
<? for($i=0; $i<5; $i­­++) { ?> 
<div class="abc"><? echo $i ?></div>    
<? } ?>

<script>
$(function() {
   $(".abc").click(function() 
     {
       var thevar= $(this).text();
       alert (thevar);
     });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have unique ids on page. due to this `$("#abc").text()` always returns value for first element in matched selector. Rather use `abc` as class. and to refer element in current context, use `$(this)`:

```
 var thevar=$(this).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in your code. Missing `});` . Id should be unique .

```
<? for($i = 0;$i<5;$i++) { ?>

<div class="abc"><? echo $i ?></div> //change

<? } ?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>



<script>
$(function() {
$(".abc").click(function() 
{
var thevar= $(this).text(); //change
alert (thevar);
});//was missing
});//was missing
</script>
```